# Android : How do I break a String into separate lines using period at the end of sentence

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ok, so I am using an API call to get a list of Release Notes for updates to my app. The app makes the API call and gets a String which has a list of what has changed, separated into different sentences with periods.

Ex. Added "Get Help" to settings menu. Fixed audio bug. Added "Forgot Password" to login.

This sentence is saved as a String in Profile called ReleaseNotes.

Now, I want to display that as a list in the Updates Activity using tvReleaseNotes.

Since the list may be anywhere from 1 to 10 sentences, how do I break it when displaying it?

If I just use the code below it displays it as one long paragraph. I want to split it at the period and make another line for each item.

```
tvReleaseNotes.setText(profile.getUserData().getReleaseNotes());
```

Update:

I managed to get the .split function working, but it is only displaying the second part of the array.I put a hyphen between the sentences, and set the hyphen as the regex.  Here is my code below...

```
    if (SharedPref.with(this).isRegister()) {
        String[] notes = releasenotes.split("-");
        for (String a : notes)
            tvInfo1.setText(a);
    } else {
        tvInfo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

And here is my .xml code for the TextView

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInfo1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sourcesanspro_semibold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="?attr/defaultTextColor"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use split function.

[split function in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/)

Comment: ok, I looked at that and it uses system.out.prntln. How do I use that to .setText to display to my TextView?

Comment: I updated my original post to show where I was able to get the .split function to work to display only the second part of the array.

Comment: String s = "Get Help.Forgot Password.";
  String[] stringArray = s.split("[.]");
  for(String separated : stringArray)
   System.out.println(separated + ".");     // i did this you can do something similar to mimic this behaviour.